# Connection to webserver - TCP reset from server

Tags: networking, firewall, webserver, windows-server-2012, iis-7

http://example.domain.com/test

This link is accessible within our LAN but not when a user on distant is using Direct Acces.
It worked until about 10 days ago, then suddenly the webserver refuse connection with the message "TCP reset from server" for traffic from users with Direct Access.

*Windows server 2012 R2 with IIS.*

*No local Firewall*

*No other Firewall is blocking the connection*

*Routing is correct.*

*nslookup works*

But still the webserver refuse connection from client with the message "TCP reset from server". But no problem if the user is in place and directly on the LAN.

*netstat - aon* displays port 80 is PID 4 listening - NT Kernel & System.

Server was patched about 12 days ago with Microsoft latest security updates.

**I hope here is text that shows what I have done and the result in a more readable form:**

**1. Using curl from server within the LAN and run aginst the problem server:**

curl -v test.domain.com/test -H "Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615"

- Trying 123.456.78.99... * TCP_NODELAY set * Connected to test.domian.com (123.456.78.99) port 80 (#0) >
  GET /test HTTP/1.1 > Host: test.domain.com/test > User-Agent: curl/7.55.1 > Accept: / > Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615 –
  < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request < Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii < Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  < Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 13:00:43 GMT < Connection: close < Content-Length: 339
  <

Bad Request

### Bad Request - Invalid Header

---

HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

–

**2. Using curl from client on distant with Direct Acces:**

curl -v test.domain.com/test -H "Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615" * Trying 123.456.78.99... * TCP_NODELAY set

- Connected to test.domain.com (123.456.78.99) port 80 (#0) > GET / HTTP/1.1 >
  Host: test.domain.com > User-Agent: curl/7.55.1 > Accept: / >
  Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615 >
- Recv failure: Connection was reset * Closing connection 0 curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset –

**As you can see I get 2 different results when I'm using curl:**

1. Result on place in LAN when type the same url in a webbrowser
2. Result on a client when user is sitting on distant with Direct Access and type the same url in a webbrowser.

**Summation:**
I cannot reach this URL when I try http: // only if I use https: //

Comment: If you're getting the error of "On port 80 is PID 4 listening" on the server, that means that there are two applications that try to take exclusive control of port 80. Normally only IIS should be listening on it. What other application do you have? Apache? Try to disable the World Wide Web Publishing service.

Comment: No, this is not the error message "On port 80 is PID 4 listening - NT Kernel & System". I can see that it looks like I wrote it like that.
This is the message we received from the server **"TCP reset from server"** when we analyzed the traffic.
No apache server.
Only IIS with lots of sites with url:s that no one through Direct Access into the LAN can access. Only if the user i sittning local on the LAN.

Comment: So when are you getting this message about PID 4 listening?

Comment: netstat - aon displays port 80 is PID 4 listening - NT Kernel & System.

Comment: That message doesn't seem very interesting. You say the problem was caused by Windows security updates. Try to temporarily disable Windows Defender and any other security software on the server, to see if this is the cause.

Comment: I can bind certificate to port 443 and then everything works, users has to type an extra S (https instead of http). Thats the next problem, becuause theres a lot of sites and urls and it seems like rewrite is quite difficult to get right. Using Condition: ^OFF$ and Redirect https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1} + see other (303).

Comment: Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration

Comment: Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: @harrymc
I´ve already done that

Comment: Trying to read the error that is throwing by doing this:
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Using curl:curl -v http://test.domain.com/test -H "Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615"
*   Trying 123.456.78.99...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.domian.com (123.456.78.99) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: test.domain.com/test
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615

Comment: < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 13:00:43 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 339
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: AND FOUND THIS ON SERVER:
2021-10-20 123.456.78.99 43728 123.456.78.99 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 400 - Header -

-Anyone?

Comment: When running curl from client on distant with Direct Acces:
curl -v http://test.domain.com/ -H "Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615"
*   Trying 123.456.78.99...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.domain.com (123.456.78.99) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: test.domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Range: bytes=00-18446744073709551615
>
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

Comment: Please add this information to your post in a readable form.

Comment: @harrymc, now I have tried to make the text more readable regarding the problem itself, please have look above.

Comment: Please ensure that end of lines are respected.